# Write dataframe to Azure EventHub with Synapse Spark using Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, azure-eventhub, azure-synapse

I want to write a dataframe with Azure Synapse Spark (in a Synapse Analytics Workspace) to a Kafka-enabled Azure Event Hub.

- Apache Spark version: **2.4**
- Python version: **3.6**
- Scala version: **2.11.12**

This exact code runs perfectly in Databricks:

```
# Build SASL:
EH_SASL = 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="$ConnectionString" password="Endpoint=sb://{}.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName={};SharedAccessKey={}";'.format(EH_NAMESPACE, EH_CLO_TRANSACTIONS_KEY_NAME, EH_CLO_TRANSACTIONS_KEY_VALUE)

# Write data:
kdf.write.format("kafka")\
.option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN")\
.option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")\
.option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", EH_SASL)\
.option("kafka.batch.size", 5000)\
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "{}.servicebus.windows.net:9093".format(EH_NAMESPACE))\
.option("kafka.request.timeout.ms", 300000)\
.option("topic", EH_CLO_TRANSACTIONS)\
.save()
```

Here, with Synapse Spark I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
```

I believe it has to do with the libraries that I am using. I am using now: **spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.0.jar**

But I also tried with:

- spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.8.jar
- spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.3.jar
- spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.0.jar
- spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.0.2.jar
- spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-2.4.7.jar
- spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-2.4.3.jar
- spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-2.4.0.jar
- azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11-2.3.17.jar
- azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11-2.3.18.jar

Every time I get errors related to missing classes, etc.

**So what library / libraries could I use for this code to work ?**

Thank you!

Comment: Eventually I managed to write to the Event hub without using Kafka: I save the dataframe to a Synapse Spark temp table, and then, in Scala I read the table and write it like this: `scalaDf.selectExpr("partitionKey", "body").write.format("eventhubs").options(ehConfig.toMap).save() `

Comment: But I would still like to use Kafka so I don't have to do the writing in 2 steps: saving to temp table and then use Scala to write to the EH....